# Expected unbalanced-classes

Tags: classification, binary-data, unbalanced-classes

I want to train a binary classifier but I have an expected unbalanced dataset (90%/10%). Should I train an unbalanced dataset or to downsample the first class? This ratio is natural and will be always present in my data for prediction.

Comment: See suggestions here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220026/can-a-classifier-trained-with-oversampled-data-be-used-to-classify-unbalanced-da/220116#220116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and see which works better.

Given that you have a training set, a validation set and a metric that you want to optimize, you can answer all sorts of questions like this by simply trying.